# Drush: can't change User Password?

Tags: 7, drush

According to http://drushcommands.com/drush-6x/user/user-password/ the command

```
drush user-password someuser --password="correct horse battery staple"
```

should change a user's password.

I am trying to change the password for user 1, but I get this error message:

```
-jailshell: !": event not found
```

I connect via ssh as root, try again, but get this error message:

```
-bash: !": event not found
```

Anyone know how I fix this? Using Drush 6.2.0. Thank you.

Comment: Any chance your actual password has an exclamation mark in it?

Comment: Yes, both the current and the proposed new password. Thanks.

Comment: Try escaping it: `--password="Exclaim\!"`

Comment: Thank you. So what does the "!" get interpreted as if it isn't escaped? It has meaning to Bash?

Comment: Yeah I forget what it's called but it's a 'history' command - it recalls previous typed commands

Comment: `!!` Is 'last command'. `!$` can move you into a folder you've just created such as `mkdir newfolder; cd !$`